# Laravel - hierarchy recursion

Tags: php, laravel, recursion

I have a `marketer` table, each marketer may has many marketer and also may belongs to one marketer. I have written this method to check if I can get multiple level of one particular marketer:

Table:

```
id   parent_id    name
1    NULL         a
2    1            b
3    2            c
4    1            d
5    3            e
6    2            f
7    4            g
```

Marketer Model:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Self::class);
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Self::class,'parent_id');
}
```

Method:

```
public function marketerWithSubs(Marketer $marketer, $index = 1, $output = [])
{
    $output = [];
    foreach ($marketer->children as $firstLevel){
        $output[1][] = $firstLevel->id . '- ' . $firstLevel->full_name;
        foreach ($firstLevel->children as $secondLevel){
            $output[2][] = $secondLevel->id . '- ' . $secondLevel->full_name;
            foreach ($secondLevel->children as $thirdLevel) {
                $output[3][] = $thirdLevel->id . '- ' . $thirdLevel->full_name;
                foreach ($thirdLevel->children as $forthLevel) {
                    $output[4][] = $forthLevel->id . '- ' . $forthLevel->full_name;
                    foreach ($forthLevel->children as $fifthLevel) {
                        $output[5][] = $fifthLevel->id . '- ' . $fifthLevel->full_name;
                        foreach ($firstLevel->children as $sixthLevel) {
                            $output[6][] = $sixthLevel->id . '- ' . $sixthLevel->full_name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Method sample output, this is what I expect, the index in the array, shows the level of (so called) submarketer and the values are the submarketers ids as an array:

```
array:6 [▼
  1 => array:27 [▶]
  2 => array:23 [▶]
  3 => array:32 [▶]
  4 => array:8 [▶]
  5 => array:5 [▼
    0 => 102
    1 => 63
    2 => 64
    3 => 65
    4 => 67
  ]
  6 => array:35 [▶]
]
```

How can I convert this to a practical method?

Comment: can you show relationship as well and expecting out .so its easy to think .thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I found the answer:

```
public function getMarketerWithSubs3(Marketer $marketer, $index = 1, $output = [])
{
    foreach ($marketer->children as $firstLevel){
        $output[$index][] = $firstLevel->id;
        $output = $this->getMarketerWithSubs3($firstLevel, $index+1, $output);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$output` probably has to be passed by reference to make it work

```
public function marketerWithSubs(Marketer $marketer, $index = 1, &$output = [])
{
    return array_reduce($marketer->children->all(), function($output, $child) {
        $output[$index][] = $child->id . '- ' . $child->full_name;
        if ($child->children->count()) {
            $this->marketerWithSubs($child, $index++, $output);
        }
        return $output;
    }, $output);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this method does not work. First parameter in `array_reduce` must be an array but object is given. I changed first parameter to be an array but with no luck.

Comment: Did you try `$marketer->children->all()`?

Comment: I will try you new solution.

Comment: `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

Comment: I'm so stupid. Forgot to rename `$firstLevel` to `$child` for consistency. Updated my answer.

Comment: I changed the name of variable, the variable is not the problem.

Comment: Well, maybe I wasn't fully awake earlier today but I bet, I found my mistake and fixed it.

Comment: Does the current answer, have the latest changes?